# Is there a practical way to secure access to mariadb by hostname in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When I deploy a mariadb and create Users for application access, I usually include the hostname or ip of the application for improved security:

```
CREATE USER 'appusser'@'hostname_or_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But in kubernetes, where I deploy applications as deployments, it seems to me fixed hostnames or ips, by which the mariadb can verify the access, are impractical.

What is a best practice here? Is there some good way that I can get my fixed hostnames or ips anyway? Or should I just accept, that I have to create users as `'appuser'@'%'`?

Comment: If you're worried about security - set corresponding `NetworkPolicies` to restrict access to your db pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) suggested in comments, you can easily restrict access to a specific `Pod` or set of `Pods` from any other `Pod` or set of `Pods` running in your kubernetes cluster by using [`NetworkPolicies`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

You can start from defining a **default deny all ingress traffic policy** as in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-traffic) example:

> You can create a "default" isolation policy for a namespace by
> creating a NetworkPolicy that selects all pods but does not allow any
> ingress traffic to those pods.
>
> [`service/networking/network-policy-default-deny-ingress.yaml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/network-policy-default-deny-ingress.yaml)
> [image]
>
> ```
> ---
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
> kind: NetworkPolicy
> metadata:
>   name: default-deny-ingress
> spec:
>   podSelector: {}
>   policyTypes:
>   - Ingress
> ```
>
> This ensures that even pods that aren't selected by any other
> NetworkPolicy will still be isolated. This policy does not change the
> default egress isolation behavior.

After that you can define other network policies allowing traffic from/to specific `Pods`.